# PhantomJSDriver: Not able to switch to newly opened browser window

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, phantomjs, ghostdriver

I have been trying to use `PhantomJSWebDriver` framework for automating an application using Headless browser. The main issue is as we can successfully switch between windows in firefox or IE windows, here I am not able to switch between windows based on handles. Please help me.

Below is the code I have tried so far.

```
    System.setProperty("phantomjs.binary.path", file.getAbsolutePath());        
    driver = new PhantomJSDriver();  
    driver.get(application url);          

    driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(100, TimeUnit.SECONDS);

    WebElement txtUsername = driver.findElement(By.id("it_C_C5"));        
    txtUsername.sendKeys("sreenis");        
    WebElement txtPassword = driver.findElement(By.id("it_C_C7"));
    txtPassword.sendKeys("sreeni");
    WebElement btnLogin = driver.findElement(By.id("ic_C_C8"));        
    btnLogin.click();

    Thread.sleep(10000);

    String winTitle = "Role profile selection";

    boolean bool = switchWindow(winTitle);
    if (bool){
        System.out.println("Page title is: " + driver.getTitle());
        driver.quit();     
    }
    else {
        System.out.println("Switch to window '" + winTitle + "' failed!");
        driver.quit();
    }

 public static boolean switchWindow(String windowtitle){

    String mainWindowsHandle = driver.getWindowHandle();
    Set<String> handles = driver.getWindowHandles();
    System.out.println(handles.size());
    for(String winHandle : handles){            
        driver.switchTo().window(winHandle);
        System.out.println(driver.getTitle());
        if(driver.getTitle().toLowerCase().equals(windowtitle)){
            return true;
        }           
    }

    driver.switchTo().window(mainWindowsHandle);
    return false;
}
```

When I tried to print the window titles in collection, it is only printing the parent window and not the other windows. I am not able to guess what is happening since nothing can be seen and it is headless testing. Please suggest me is there any other way so that I can test the app with many browser windows.

Comment: whats the error you are getting on console? you may want to provide the stack trace.

Comment: No Error but, it is unable to find the window to switch in Window handles collection. Have you tried this, if yes please tell me what mistake I have done. I have even added Thread.Sleep(10000) :(

Comment: which browser are you using.Is it IE??

Comment: @AkhilK: It is PhantomJS no browser is visible, it is Headless browser testing.

Comment: @harsha.cs, how would you know, it is unable to find the window, it must have thrown an error right? can I have the trace of the log?

Comment: @pArAs: See my above code, I am just call switchToWindow() function, if it returns false I am quitting driver. So inside switchToWindow it is looping only one time and the window title inside the function is same as the earlier opened window, it is not getting new title and hence it is returning false, so it is going to else condition and quitting driver without any error. Hope you understood :)

Comment: which phantomjs driver version are you using?

Comment: @pArAs: PhantomJSDriver with Selenium

Comment: maybe its because it has no window handle really, after all it is headless?

Answer (score 0):

```
Actions act = new Actions(d);
    act.contextClick(elements).sendKeys("W").perform();

    Set<String> win = d.getWindowHandles();
    Iterator <String> itrwin = win.iterator();
    String parent = itrwin.next();
    String child = itrwin.next();
    d.switchTo().window(child);
```

identify an web element first using findElement() and store it in element.

Comment: Pankaj: No it is not working. It is showing same old window handler :(